# How to reproduce UnicodeEncodeError?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unicode

I get an error in a production system, which I fail to reproduce in a development environment:

```
with io.open(file_name, 'wt') as fd:
    fd.write(data)
```

Exception:

```
  File "/home/.../foo.py", line 18, in foo
    fd.write(data)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 6400: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I already tried to but a lot of strange characters into the variable `data`.

But up to now I was not able to reproduce an `UnicodeEncodeError`.

What needs to be in `data` to get an `UnicodeEncodeError`?

## Update

```
python -c 'import locale; print locale.getpreferredencoding()'
UTF-8
```

## Update2

If I call `locale.getpreferredencoding()` via shell and via web request, the encoding is "UTF-8".

I updated my exception handling in my code and log the `getpreferredencoding()` since some days. Now it happened again (up to now I am not able to force or reproduce this), and the encoding is "ANSI_X3.4-1968"!

I have no clue where this encoding gets set ....

This puts my problem into a different direction. Leaving this question useless. My problem is now: Where does the preferred encoding get altered? But this is not part of this question.

A big thank you, for all who

Comment: You know, without any more information that lets us reproduce your issue (you know, a [MCVE]), there are no other answers to give. I'm highly sceptical that *with only the code you've shown* that `locale.getpreferredencoding()` is really UTF-8 *when you hit that error*.

Comment: You could also just check the encoding that was picked for the file; `io.TextIOWrapper` has an `encoding` attribute. It'll be set to ASCII in this specific case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are relying on the default encoding for the platform; when that default encoding can't support the Unicode characters you are writing to the file, you get an encoding exception.

From the [`io.open()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open):

> *encoding* is the name of the encoding used to decode or encode the file. This should only be used in text mode. The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever [`locale.getpreferredencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) returns), but any encoding supported by Python can be used.

For your specific situation, the default returned by `locale.getpreferredencoding()` is ASCII, so any Unicode character outside the ASCII range would cause this issue, U-0080 and up.

Note that the locale is taken from your environment; if it is ASCII, that typically means the locale is set to the [POSIX default locale, `C`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-2521/overview-1002/index.html).

Specify the encoding explicitly:

```
with io.open(file_name, 'wt', encoding='utf8') as fd:
    fd.write(data)
```

I used UTF-8 as an example; what you pick depends entirely on your use cases and the data you are trying to write out.

Comment: locale.getpreferredencoding() returns UTF-8. AFAIK every string can be encoded to utf8. That's why I don't understand the content of "data".

Comment: @guettli: *on the system that raises the exception*? Because your traceback clearly indicates that it is the `fd.write` call that causes this issue, and the only codec that that will use is the encoding set for `fd`.

Comment: @guettli: make sure that when this exception occurs you capture both `repr(data)` and `locale.getpreferredencoding()`. Tripple-check your assumptions about what `fd` is and that the traceback is really pointing to `fd.write()`.

Comment: @guettli: I am, of course, assuming that `io.open()` is still the standard library function and not some other implementation.

Comment: Yes, io is the standard. But I guess `data` comes from a module written in C. Maybe it contains an internally broken string. I guess you can't create something like this in usual (non-c) python.

Comment: @guettli: then you'd be able to reproduce the issue with `data.encode(locale.getdefaultlocale())`. I'd add an exception handler there and log the information and the outcome of that call. I certainly can't help you if you are breaking Python internals somewhere.

Comment: @guettli: not that I think it likely, however.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this to reproduce the error:

```
with open(filename, 'wt', encoding='ascii') as fd:
    fd.write('\xa0')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test.py", line 2, in
>   
>       fd.write('\xa0')
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa0' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Sure, but the OP is not using `encoding=`. So where does the encoding come from in their case?

Comment: @MartijnPieters As the OP says in the comments, `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns `utf-8` so what is happening here?

Comment: I've tried to get more information from the OP about that. They can't get that exception *and* `locale.getprefrerredencoding()` being `UTF-8`, not with the code they posted. I posted my answer before the bounty was placed, so apparently the OP doesn't believe me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `write` in a `try`/`except` and save the data into a binary file -- you'll be able to see exactly what data is giving you issues:

```
with io.open(file_name, 'wt') as fd:
    try:
        fd.write(data)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        with open('/path/to/save/error.bin', 'wb') as err:
            err.write(data)
        raise
```

Comment: It's not as if the exception isn't already telling you what codec is being used. That's the real issue here; why is writing is triggering an encoding to ASCII. It is interesting to note that the OP asked about implicit encoding triggers just before this question: [Why UnicodeEncodeError during \*\*decoding\*\*?](//stackoverflow.com/q/41567720)